Excel: How to refer multiple cells to use SUMIFS formula
I have created the following excel file and I want to extract only the column A that contains 2024/01 and 2024/02 and add the column B.

So I entered the following formula using {}.
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{"2024/01","2024/02"})

This is successful.
However, if I enter 2024/01,2024/02 in column C and enter the following formula, I get an error.
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{C:C})

How should I deal with the calculation referring to the cells in column C?
I tried to enter the following formula, but it said "spill".
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,CHOOSE({1,2},C1,C2)


Wrap within SUM() function: =SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B3,A2:A3,C2:C3))

Look at this solution by @ScottCraner Sir : Aptly matches with your request
